# FindViewById in android studio

Tags: android-studio

hi im beginner an trying to define a button on android studio. i get an as i write "FindV" and android studio have no suggestion for me. if complete code myself, get error. here is the code:

```
package com.example.neomn.myapplication1;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              Button start = (Button) FindV   // no suggestions
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to type as findViewById?
It should start from small letter f.

Answer (score 0):

Without completing  `findViewById` you will get error if you run.

Check if Power Save Mode on File menu is disabled,that may cause disabling auto complete features

Comment: its enable and working . it just not work in this case